# How to get value of a column based on the maximum of another column in case of DataFrame.groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe which looks like this.

`id        YearReleased      Artist     count
168             2015             Muse      1
169             2015          Rihanna      3
170             2015     Taylor Swift      2
171             2016   Jennifer Lopez      1
172             2016          Rihanna      3
173             2016       Underworld      1
174             2017         Coldplay      1
175             2017       Ed Sheeran      2`

I want to get the maximum count for each year and then get the corresponding Artist name.

Something like this:

YearReleased  Artist

2015          Rihanna
2016          Rihanna
2017       Ed Sheeran

I have tried using a loop to iterate over the rows of the dataframe and create another dictionary with key as year and value as artist. But when I try to convert that dictionary to a dataframe, the keys are mapped to columns instead of rows.

Can somebody guide me to have a better approach to this without having to loop over the dataframe and instead use some inbuilt pandas method to achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at `idxmax`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('YearReleased')['count'].idxmax()]
Out[445]: 
    id  YearReleased     Artist  count
1  169          2015    Rihanna      3
4  172          2016    Rihanna      3
7  175          2017  EdSheeran      2
```

Comment: @JeetBanerjee yw:-) happy coding

Comment: I think this method no longer works...

Answer (score 6):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) :

```
idx = df.groupby(['YearReleased'])['count'].transform(max) == df['count']
```

and then use this indexer:

```
df[idx]
Out[14]: 
    id  YearReleased      Artist  count
1  169          2015     Rihanna      3
4  172          2016     Rihanna      3
7  175          2017  Ed Sheeran      2
```