# Get the latest data for each customer from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get the latest data for every customer regardless of other attributes in the dataframe.

My dataframe looks like this

[image]

My output should look like this

[image: My output should look like this]

I have tried 'df.iloc[df.groupby('customer')['date'].idxmax()]' but I am getting ValueError.

"ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df = df.iloc[df.groupby('cutomer')['date'].idxmax()]

~\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
653             if self.obj.ndim == 1:
654                 # this can be called recursively, so need to raise ValueError
--> 655                 raise ValueError
656
657             # GH#3688 try to operate item-by-item

ValueError: "

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you please remove the link to the image and instead post that as clear text. It would be best if you can post the information as dataframe so its easy for everyone to extract.

Comment: Looks like you want to do a max of date based on other attributes. Did you try any code yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value of a column based on the maximum of another column in case of DataFrame.groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263437/how-to-get-value-of-a-column-based-on-the-maximum-of-another-column-in-case-of-d)

Comment: df.loc[df.groupby(['Customer','attr1','attr2'])['date'].idxmax()]

Comment: 'df.loc[df.groupby(['Customer','attr1','attr2'])['date'].idxmax()]' won't work as it is dependent on other attributes in the dataframe. My output should be dependent only on the customer and it should return all the rows which are recent to that particular customer.

Comment: 'df.loc[df.groupby(['memberid'])['collected_on'].idxmax()]' should ideally work but I am getting ValueError. Then I changed my "date" columns which was a datetime object and reformatted it to just have the date field using 'df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date()))' after which I don't get the ValueError anymore but I get a wrong output

Comment: Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's really the same as this one: [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-count-in-groups-using-groupby)
In this case the code would look like this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
idx = df.groupby('Customer')['date'].transform(max) == df['date']
df[idx]
```